# jQuery iframe keyword

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

How could I check if an iframe contains a certain text keyword then display/show it...?

The ocr iframe will contain dynamically generated text, and I need to get certain parts

The code I have that will not work:

```
    <iframe id="ocr"></iframe>

    $('#ocr:contains("keyword")').addClass("highlight");

    if ($('#ocr').text().indexOf("keyword") != -1){alert('found keyword');}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to analyse the contents of the iframe, not just the iframe element itself. You can use [`contents()`](http://api.jquery.com/contents/).

For example:

```
if($("#ocr").contents().find('body').text().indexOf("keyword") != -1)
{
    alert('Keyword found');
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$("#ocr").highlightTextarea({
words: ["\\B@\\w+"],
color: "lightblue",
id: "mark"
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/sQVe/uhHnN/3/

Try something like this...